# $\int_a^b M(x)\eta''(x)dx=0$ for all $\eta$ implies $M(x) = c_0 + c_1x$ proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Here's a lemma that my book proves:

> If $M(x)\in C[a,b]$ and $$\int_a^b M(x)\eta'(x)dx = 0$$ for all $\eta(x)\in C^1[a,b]$ such that $\eta(a)=\eta(b)=0$, then $$M(x)=c,$$ a constant, for all $x\in [a,b]$.

It then asks the reader to prove a related lemma:

> Let $M(x)\in C[a,b]$ be a continuous function on the closed interval $a\le x\le b$ that satisfies $$ \int_a^b M(x)\eta''(x)dx = 0$$ for all $\eta(x)\in C^2[a,b]$ satisfying $$\eta(a)=\eta(b)=\eta'(a)=\eta'(b)=0.$$  Then $M(x)=c_0+c_1x$ for suitable constants $c_0$ and $c_1$.

My thoughts: If $\eta(x) \in C^2[a,b]$, then $\eta'(x)\in C^1[a,b]$ and thus the exact conditions of the former lemma applies (with the role of $\eta$ in the first lemma being played by $\eta'$ in the second) meaning that $M(x)$ should just be constant, not $c_0+c_1x$.  Why is this reasoning false?

Also hints on how that second lemma would be proven appreciated. ;)

Comment: I don't know the exact reason and I can't find my copy of a calculus of variations book.  I believe the proof for the first lemma involves integration by parts.  This version should involve you doing it twice.  Try working through the alegbra and I think you'll find the proof.

Comment: Actually you can't do IBP in this case because $M$ is only continuous and $\eta$ is only $C^2$.  So no derivatives can be taken.  The proof of the first involved a smart choice of $\eta$ -- which annoyingly won't work this time, so I've got to come up with a new smart choice.  I'm working on that now.

Comment: Ok then.  Try setting n = ((x-c)(x-d))^3.  Where a and b are within [a,b] otherwise n = 0.  That should do what you want for the proof.  I think.

Comment: Just to point out why in second case you CANNOT simply apply the first case. Let $\eta(x)\in C^2[a,b]$ such that $η(a)=η(b)=η′(a)=η′(b)=0.$ and put $\psi=\eta'$. Then $\psi$ is NOT a generic $C^1$ function vanishing at the ends. Now $\psi$ satisfies ONE MORE restriction: $\int_a^b\psi(x) dx=0$, that is it has zero mean, it is not the generic $\eta$ of the first statement.